# Setting PATH environment variable not working in Fedora 17

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, tomcat, fedora, java

I'm pretty new to Apache Tomcat and somewhat new to Linux altogether.  I am trying to install the JDK, which is a prereq for Apache Tomcat.  I downloaded and untarred the JDK to /usr/java and now I'm trying to set the environment path.  I opened root's .bash_profile and added the following lines:

JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17
export JAVA_HOME

PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH

But after I log out and back into the root profile and type

echo $JAVA_HOME

to test the changes all it returns is a blank line.  Echoing $PATH doesn't return a path with the jdk directory included either.

I'm not sure what I did wrong, can anyone help?

Comment: Beyond the obvious problem, this is not where you should be setting this variable in Tomcat. `/path/to/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh` is the recommended place for container variables. For a more detailed overview of this topic, you can refer to a related answer of mine [here](http://serverfault.com/a/472758/152073). You can skip the "looking for customizations" step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add that to your login script I believe, those changes are erased @ logout if I'm not mistaken. I've had the same issue on debian (Ubuntu) machines. Try manually adding the Java path to $Path like

```
PATH=/usr/java/jkd:$PATH
export PATH
```

**Update**

related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session